# Regarding auth0 security

Tags: security, oauth, auth0

I am implementing auth0 on my site(jQuery) and on server side(Node).

When user logs in **idToken** is issued, which is further passed to my **NodeServer** to verify using **checkJWT**. After verifying I am POSTING **https://{AUTH_DOMAIN}/oauth/token** with body containing **client_secret, clien_id, audience, grant_type** . In response I get **Access_token**.
Which I can further use for fetching userDetails or any other api.

I am wondering if user steals the **Access_token** or **idToken** and tries to hit API and he would be able to access the data.

How can I manage this...?
Or is there anything that I am missing..?

Answer (score 0):

idToken is very short-lived, Access_token also lives not so long, may be even 1 day is I'm not mistaking.
So, if Man-In-The-Middle doesn't have access to refresh_token he has only a limited time to login to the system.